# How do I kill a screen session if it has no running processes?

Tags: server, java, process, minecraft

I use `screen` to run a Minecraft server, and I restart it every day. This is my start code:

```
screen -mdS mcserver
screen -S mcserver -p 0 -X stuff "java -Xmx4G -jar server.jar^M"
```

This is my stop code:

```
screen -S mcserver -p 0 -X stuff "stop^M"
sleep 10
screen -XS mcserver quit
```

Sending the command `stop` makes the Minecraft server save the world, which can take a few seconds. Is there a way to make the program wait until `java` (The Minecraft server) isn't running and then kill `screen`? If I kill `screen` before I send `stop` to Minecraft, the world can have a few glitches. (Player items desync from the world blocks, people lose items, and accidentally duplicate stuff)

Comment: I find it much simpler and safer to let systemd do all that work. My server runs as a systemd service (instead of multiple `screen` scripts), and restart/backup is on a systemd timer. Server output is logged anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems scriptable to me. You could try doing something simply like this

```
#!/bin/bash

#Stop the minecraft server
screen -S mcserver -p 0 -X stuff "stop^M"

while true
do
  echo "checking for java..."
  sleep 2
  ps aux |grep 'server.jar' |grep -v grep
  [ $? -eq 1 ] && break
done

screen -XS mcserver quit
```

This basically loops until server.jar is not found in the process list, then it breaks out of the loop. Since the loop is broken, it should be safe to shutdown the screen session